# Continuous $f$ on $[0,1]$ is not one-to-one.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We have continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ with $f([0,1])=[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

> Prove $f$ is never one-to-one?

I know I should show what I tried but I unable to think how to start on this one. I would appreciate some hints so I can update what I tried.

Comment: Do you know much topology? Specifically, are you familiar with the terms "compact" and "homeomorphism?"

Comment: Yes, i am a beginner but I am familiar with these terms

Comment: It sounds like you are jumping ahead without mastering some basic concepts.  In any case it is futile for Readers to suggest how you "can update what [you] tried" unless you share that.  There are many ways to provide context besides sharing what approach was tried, such as explaining where you encountered the problem or what makes it especially interesting or important.

Answer (score 0):

Show that such a function would need to be a homeomorphism (hint: domains and codomain are both hausdorff and compact).  Show that these spaces are not homeomorphic (classic approach: think about removing one point)

Comment: Can you please share more info on removing one point approach?

Comment: @Shady Think about connectedness. When you remove an interior point from $[0, 1]$ you split it in two pieces. Is the same true of $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$?